# unsyncing an iphone 4

Tags: iphone

Someone synced my iphone 4 with their ipad without my knowledge or permission. I have tried to find a setting or action on my iphone to "unsync" my phone from the ipad or other devices, but was unsuccessful. what can i do now?

Comment: How do you turn it off?

Comment: here you go http://ipod.about.com/od/iphoneipodbattery/qt/disable-auto-sync.htm

Answer (score 2):

What data is syncing with the iPad?  It sounds like the other person logged into their iCloud account on your phone which would give you any or all of: mail, contacts, calendars, reminders, safari bookmarks, notes, passbook, keychain, photos.  Is that what you're seeing?  If so you need to log your phone out of their iCloud account.  Go into Settings -> General -> iCloud and at the bottom you'll see "Delete Account".

If the other person enabled Find My iPhone with their iCloud account you **MUST** have them disable it on your phone, which they can do that directly on the phone or on iCloud.com.  There's no other way to disable it.  If you try a full reset the phone will boot back up with the Activation lock (aka: iCloud lock) switched on and it'll be nothing but a paperweight until the other person unlocks it.